# Installing SCONS without root access

Tags: linux, installation, root, scons

Is there any way to install [SCONS](http://www.scons.org/) without root access?

Comment: Off-topic for SO; belongs on [sf]

Comment: @JimGarrison - Agreed that the question is not about development per-se, but SCons is a build tool used by developers. And SO guidelines cover "software tools". Server Fault is oriented toward system/network admins who will typically have root. If this question belongs somewhere else, I would suggest superuser or askubuntu (if appropriate).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, download the source distribution and follow the instructions in the [SCons User Guide](http://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user/x167.html) to install without admin privileges.